# И еще о Красном Кресте

Tags: пунктуация, ономастика

Тут только что задали вопрос, нужно ли брать в кавычки Красный Крест как название организации, и был ответ, что не нужно. Даже в пример привели Международное Движение Красного Креста и Красного Полумесяца.
Но мне интересно, а почему, собственно, не нужно? Это ведь название, значит, по идее, должно браться в кавычки.

Comment: @Akabane, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В кавычки не берутся реальные собственные имена (различающиеся прежде всего синтаксической сочетаемостью).В таких названиях все слова употребляются в прямом значении. Ср.: Большой театр, Театр сатиры, Театр на Юго-Западе -  это реальные собственные имена, в них присутствует синтаксическая сочетаемость, кавычки не нужны.
Но: такие имена тоже могут употребляться с кавычками, если они сочетаются с родовым словом.Ср.: театр ''Современник", театр ''Школа современной пьесы" - условные наименования, не сочетающиеся синтаксически с родовым словом.Они заключаются в кавычки. Аналогично: парк Дружбы, но: парк ''Сокольники", Коммунистическая партия Российской Федерации, но: партия "Яблоко" и т. д.
Однако  при употреблении без родового наименования они, в отличие от условных названий, пишутся без кавычек. 
Поэтому, основываясь на этом правиле, нужно писать:  Красный крест,  Общество Красного Креста и Красного Полумесяца